# Energy based model of perceptron loss?

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, conv-neural-network, loss-functions, perceptron

[image: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-06.pdf]

I was reading LeCun's tutorial paper on energy-based models of cost functions, and came upon this table. I don't understand how he got the equation for perceptron loss. Can someone clarify how that equation meshes with this, which I believe is the regular loss function:

[image: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~xfern/classes/cs534/notes/perceptron-4-11.pdf]

I'm new to neural networks and information theory, so if answers could come with examples, that would be extremely helpful.